# Indexing Array of Handle Class Objects

Tags: matlab, object, handle

I have a handle class called `Subject`. I also have a handle array called Subjects.

`Subjects = [];`

During the execution of my program, I create a subject (like `subject1`) and I assign its properties. Once I'm done with the subject I add its handle to the handle array (I think) and move on to the next subject.

```
Subjects = [Subjects; subject1];
```

At the end I expect `Subjects` to look like

```
Subjects = [subject1Handle, subject2Handle, ect...]
```

Now I want to pull properties from `subject1`. 
I have tried these commands

```
subject1 = Subjects[1]
subject1 = Subjects(1)
subject1 = Subjects(1,1)
```

None of these work. I get an error "Not enough input arguments." Maybe matlab believes I want to create a new subject, so it expects input arguments?

This should be a really simple thing, I just don't know the syntax, and I can't find it in the documentation.

Matlab version 2016a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies when creating your handles array.

Using the `[]` creates and empty double array. You want to create a Subject array.
You can use the empty constructor to create your empty array like so:

```
Subjects = Subject.empty;
```

Then you should be able to add handles into the array like you want.

To retrieve a handle, indexing the array with parentheses should work.